MariaDb inistialization script
I am trying to set up MariaDB in docker-compose. When initializes, it should have the following:

root allowed to connect from anywhere (%)
a specific DB created
a specific user created
the user granted all access on that db.

I made a script for that, which is mounted as a volume in the container description.
--init-file parameter sounds good, but it can't do the job as the mysql database itself is not created yet at that point at the first run. Hence the mysqld startup fails with:
[ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist

Is there any way to run some script at startup but after everything is initialized, or any other way to create these artifacts at the first run?
